# Excel values in different sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel sheet like the one below

Sheet name:`Raw`

Data:

> 1. Blue  value1  value2  value3  value4
> 2. Green value5  value6  value7  value8
> 3. Black value9  value10 value11 value12
> 4. Blue  value13 value14 value15 value16
> 5. Green value17 value18 value19 value20  . . .

I want to automatically create different sheets named Blue, Green, Black and add these rows in there. So I would like to have:

Sheet name:`Blue`

> 1. Blue value1 value2 value3 value4
> 2. Blue value13 value14 value15 value16

Sheet name: Green

> 1. Green value5 value6 value7 value8
> 2. Green value17 value18 value19 value20

Sheet name: Black

> 1. Black value9 value10 value11 value12

Any idea?

Comment: Not strictly coding related, possibly belongs on http://superuser.com/

Comment: It depends on how you can implement the solution

Comment: @Gary This will most likely require a vba solution, is probably OK here.  @ Midis That said, what have you tried so far, or are you just asking for someone to code it for you?

Comment: I tried to do it with perl but I was asked to do it with a more straightforward way so it can be reusable in my work. I dont know excel or vba and that why I am asking. I dont want someone to code it for me. I want an opinion... Stop commenting without reason. If you dont know, you dont know

Comment: This question was cross-posted on superuser.com as [http://superuser.com/questions/278913/excel-values-in-different-sheets]...

Comment: I added it because they told me to ask there..

Answer (score 1):

Heres a quick routine to get you started...

```
Sub CopyColorRows()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim shData As Worksheet
    Dim shBlue As Worksheet, shGreen As Worksheet, shBlack As Worksheet
    Dim rw As Range

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set shData = wb.Sheets("Data")

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    On Error Resume Next

    Set shBlue = wb.Sheets("Blue")
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Err.Clear
    Else
        shBlue.Delete
    End If
    Set shBlue = wb.Sheets.Add
    shBlue.Name = "Blue"

    Set shGreen = wb.Sheets("Green")
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Err.Clear
    Else
        shGreen.Delete
    End If
    Set shGreen = wb.Sheets.Add
    shGreen.Name = "Green"

    Set shBlack = wb.Sheets("Black")
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Err.Clear
    Else
        shBlack.Delete
    End If
    Set shBlack = wb.Sheets.Add
    shBlack.Name = "Black"

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    On Error GoTo 0

    For Each rw In shData.UsedRange.Rows
        Select Case rw.Cells(1, 1)
        Case "Blue"
            rw.Copy shBlue.UsedRange.Offset(1, 0)
        Case "Green"
            rw.Copy shGreen.UsedRange.Offset(1, 0)
        Case "Black"
            rw.Copy shBlack.UsedRange.Offset(1, 0)
        End Select
    Next
End Sub
```